# String to array js

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

```js
var a = 'var a = [{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","logo":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/730\/d0595ff02f5c79fd19b06f4d6165c3fda2372820.jpg","friendly_name":"CSGO","friendlyURL":"CSGO","availStatLinks":{"achievements":true,"global_achievements":true,"stats":false,"gcpd":false,"leaderboards":false,"global_leaderboards":false},"hours_forever":"62","last_played":1521032036},{"appid":371420,"name":"Teddy Floppy Ear - The Race","logo":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/371420\/f9bb34b5d07c7827a5f5f2b37da87f24b34843b8.jpg","friendlyURL":371420,"availStatLinks":{"achievements":true,"global_achievements":true,"stats":false,"gcpd":false,"leaderboards":false,"global_leaderboards":false},"hours_forever":"7.3","last_played":1519572693}]';
```

В общем, есть огромный массив (выше его часть) и он в виде строки. Как его сделать в виде массива?

Comment: используйте функцию eval()

Comment: JSON.parse, но сперва надо удалить все лишнее.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! eval() подошел вполне.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) У вас Syntax Error, на конце нет `]`

2) Как сказал @ДенисЛагуткин используйте `eval()`

Пример

```
 var a ='....'
 eval(a);
 console.log(a[0]["appid"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Лучше всего использовать функцию [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Пример использования

```js
/* заметим что значение это строка */
var numbersString = "[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]";

var numbers = JSON.parse(numbersString);

console.log(numbers);
```

Функцию `eval` использовать без необходимости не рекомендуется. Смотрим [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

В вашем случае для того что бы функция заработала надо перед её выполнением подготовить строку, убрать из начала `var a =`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = 'var a = [{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","logo":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/730/d0595ff02f5c79fd19b06f4d6165c3fda2372820.jpg","friendly_name":"CSGO","friendlyURL":"CSGO","availStatLinks":{"achievements":true,"global_achievements":true,"stats":false,"gcpd":false,"leaderboards":false,"global_leaderboards":false},"hours_forever":"62","last_played":1521032036},{"appid":371420,"name":"Teddy Floppy Ear - The Race","logo":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/371420/f9bb34b5d07c7827a5f5f2b37da87f24b34843b8.jpg","friendlyURL":371420,"availStatLinks":{"achievements":true,"global_achievements":true,"stats":false,"gcpd":false,"leaderboards":false,"global_leaderboards":false},"hours_forever":"7.3","last_played":1519572693}]';

let re = /^.*?([[{][\s\S]+[}\]]).*?$/,    // регулярное выражение для поиска 
    jsonStrTr = a.match(re),              // ищем подстроку, которая может оказаться JSON'ом
    obj; 
if (jsonStrTr)
  obj = JSON.parse(jsonStrTr[1]);         // парсим совпадение, если таковое имеется

// вывод в читаемом виде
document.body.style.cssText = 'font: 14px monospace; white-space: pre;'; 
document.body.textContent = 'Результат:\n' + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
```